# How to give condition in $routeProvider .otherwise?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project where I have two different dashboards for admin and users. and I need to show a default page if their is any url mistake.

At the moment I have only below code and it will show only one default page which is for user dashboard

```
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/dashboard' });
```

how can I change it to `.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/adminDashboard' });` when I need to show it for admin.

Comment: How do you determine if user is an admin?

Comment: I will get to know by the service call " rollId=1 (admin), rollId=2 (user)"

Comment: Could use a `resolve` in admin dash when() and  set it as default. Redirect in resolve if not an admin

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin_dashboad_path');  .....if you know when you have to switch to admin just paste the admin dashboad path to the given function.

Comment: @charlietfl do you any any example so that I can refer it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know How do you determine if user is an admin. but I assume you have any flag variable with value of true or false.

If you determined the current user is an admin, then Simply try this //IsAdmin is a flag variable for the current role is admin or not.

```
redirectTo: IsAdmin === true? '/adminDashboard' : '/dashboard'
```

### *Important:

> Otherwise you should get the current user role(admin or user) in 
>   dashboard controller. then you can redirect the route with the condition like below.

```
if($scope.currentRole=="Admin")
{
 $location.path('/adminDashboard');
}else{
$location.path('/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: So in this case redirectTo will act as .otherwise right?

Comment: yes! You should check this in `dashboard` controller.

Comment: I am writing this condition inside app.js I dont think so if condition will work here.

Comment: inside the app.js. how could you getting the service response? Kindly provide more code.

Comment: I can get it through localstorage.

Comment: then you could check the `localStorage.get("LocalStorageName")` instead of `$scope.currentRole` on the if condition in dashboard controller. no need change in  this `otherwise({ redirectTo: '/dashboard' });` @User123

Comment: Would not do this in controller. Better ways to do it

Comment: @charlietfl But the OP  couldn't get the current role id in app.js file. Because the service will run after completion run of app.js file.

Comment: @RameshRajendran so it can be done in a resolve before needing to run a controller

Answer (score 0):

In my application there were parameters in the url. If thats the case then you use something like this

```
$location.search().myParam; 

Lets say i have token as query param 

location.search.includes("token")
```